# Determine the shock curve and sketch characteristics in $xt$-plane

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

> Let
>   $$\begin{equation} u(x,t)= \begin{cases} \frac{x-2}{t+2}&;x>\xi(t)\\0&;x<\xi(t)\end{cases} \end{equation}$$
>   be a weak solution to $u_t+(\frac{u^2}{2})_x=0$ in $\mathbb R\times(0,\infty)$. The unknown shock curve $x=\xi(t)$ starts at the origin,
>   then determine the shock curve and draw a picture with characteristics in the $xt$-plane.

we find characteristics curve by Rankine-Hugoniot, i'm not sure to sketch the diagram.
Please, someone give me a detail.

Answer (score 1):

This is the inviscid Burgers' equation. The Rankine-Hugoniot condition
$$
\xi'(t) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\xi(t)-2}{t+2} + 0\right)
$$
with initial position $\xi(0)=0$ gives the shock trajectory
$\xi(t) = 2 - \sqrt{2t+4}.$
Characteristic curves are obtained via the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) with initial data
$$
u(x,0) =
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&0     & &\text{if}\quad x<0,\\
&x/2-1 & &\text{if}\quad x>0.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Here is a sketch of the $x$-$t$ plane so-obtained:

[image: char]